# Conversion of char * to string

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone have an idea how to convert char* to string. Actually, I have a function which returns value as char*  and now i need to store/copy  std::string.
I have tried something like

`char *sResult = (char*)malloc(1024);
std:string line;
line= line+ sResult`

Thanks and regards,
Sam

Comment: Sorry that code makes no sense. Why would you want to convert uninitialized data to a `std::string`?

Comment: just like Johannes has remarked... your code makes no sense. You should better simply create an empty std::string. Using uninitialized memory is a very dangereous and buggy behaviour. You cannt assume anything on what is memory when it is to be used initialized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
std::string line(szResult);
```

Comment: okay, but as Johannes has remarked: samprat code makes no sense, since the char* is not initialized, why would he want to convert it to a string ? he could as well create an empty string simply. Much simplier.

Comment: std::string line(szResult);
Thanks Guys , It worked flawlessly

Comment: @Ste: I think that code was just for demonstration purpose. Another trick I use to deal with the std::strings - line.insert(nPosition, szCharText);

Answer (score 9):

There is an ***implicit conversion*** from `const char*` to `std::string`(via nonexplicit constructor). So the following will all work (suppose ch is `const char*` or `char*`)

```
std::string s (ch);
std::string s = ch;
s = ch;
f(ch); //where f is declared to take std::string
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

The std::string class has a constructor taking a `const char *`so you can do

```
char *foo;
/* .... initialize foo ... */
std::string some_string(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

std:string line;
line.append(sResult);
or
std::string line(sResult);

Answer (score 1):

If you have a line of data that isn't necessarily a C-string, you use string's constructor

```
std::string s(sResult, sSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `char* ptrToString = "wharever"; std::string szMyStdString = ptrToStrin`g

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to type to colons for
the scope specifier like so:

**std::string** line;

And then depending on the C library you are using the + operator might not
be overloaded to handle char* string so you should be better of
using:

line = line + **std::string(sResult)**;

Though your implementation, should work if you fix the scope specifier, 
in full-featured c++ standard library implementations like ms or gcc ones.