# Convert char* to string&

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string &s1 = argv[0];           // error
    const string &s2 = argv[0];     // ok

    argv[0] = "abc";
    cout << argv[0] << endl;        // prints "abc"
    cout << s2 << endl;             // prints program name
}
```

I receive the following error for `s1`:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}' from expression of type 'char*'
```

Then why does the compiler accept `s2`?

Interestingly, when I assign a new value to `argv[0]` then `s2` does not change. Does the compiler ignore that it's a reference and copies the value anyway? Why does it happen?

I write this in Code::Blocks 16.01 (mingw). The same happens with/without `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Would you say that `argv[0]` is an `std::string`?

Comment: "Then why does the compiler accept s2?" because of implicit conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553896/conversion-of-char-to-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Then why does the compiler accept s2?

Because a constant reference can bind to a temporary, and `std::string` has a constructor that can take a `char *` for a parameter.

That assignment constructs a so-called "temporary" object, and binds a constant reference to it.

> Interestingly, when I assign a new value to argv[0] then s2 does not
>   change.

Why should it change? `s2` is a separate object. A `std::string` object does not maintain a pointer to a `char *` that created it. There are many ways to create a `std::string`. The actual string is owned by the object. If the `std::string` is constructed from a literal character string, it gets copied into the `std::string`. So, if the literal character string comes from a buffer, and the buffer is subsequently modified, it has no effect on the `std::string`.

Comment: The constructor of a `std::string` takes a `const char *` for a parameter. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you're not, @skypjack. That's why I wrote "can take", instead of "takes".

Comment: And with special emphasis on **a const** reference can bind to a temporary

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
const string &s2 = argv[0];
```

Creates a new `string` instance, copying the contents of `argv[0]`, and binds the reference to it. Later, this copy is outputted, which is now unrelated to the actual value of `argv[0]`.

The temporary string objects lifetime, created in the quoted line, is expanded to the scope of the block, because a const reference was formed to it. See more at: [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the code asks the compiler to construct a temporary `std::string` object whose content is a copy of `argv[0]`. While it's fun and maybe useful to look at the details of which one works and why, in terms of actually writing code, messing around with temporaries isn't necessary and leads to confusion. Just create an object:

```
std::string s1 = argv[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
const string &s2 = argv[0];
```

is equal to:

```
const string &s2 = std::string(argv[0]);
```

So s2 contains a const reference to a temporary string, which copied the content from argv[0].